# OR not working as expected in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean-logic

In Postgresql when I make a SELECT using the OR does not seem to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?
For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM toorder 
WHERE product_id = 1193 
AND status = 'NO' 
OR status = 'YES'
```

The result give me results that are not product_id = 1193 also.
The status field has 3 answers; YES, NO and DON in this example.
Anybody has any idea why it does not work?

Comment: There are two ways to parenthesize the where clause. Try them both. Another way would be `SELECT * FROM toorder WHERE product_id = 1193 AND status IN ( 'NO' , 'YES' )`

Answer (score 5):

The `OR` operator works just fine, what is happening is that what you are doing is in fact equivalent to:

```
-- WRONG (not expected):
SELECT * FROM toorder
WHERE (product_id = 1193 AND status = 'NO') OR (status = 'YES')
```

Which means you are getting all results with `product_id = 1193` that have `status = 'NO'`, but also all other (no matter which `product_id`) with `status = 'YES'`. That happens [because `AND` operator has precedence over `OR` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) (in fact `OR` is the one with least precedence).

So, in your case you should use explicit parenthesis to make the precedence as you desire:

```
-- CORRECT (expected):
SELECT * FROM toorder
WHERE product_id = 1193 AND (status = 'NO' OR status = 'YES')
```

It is advisable to always use parenthesis when you mix different kind of operators, even in cases that you want the default precedence, it helps to make the code more clear and increase the maintainability.

Complementing... As @wildplasser suggested, in this specific case you can simplify things even more by using the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM toorder
WHERE product_id = 1193 AND status IN ('NO', 'YES')
```

Which is logically equivalent to the previous query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM toorder WHERE product_id = 1193 AND (status = 'NO' OR status = 'YES')
```

Put brackets round the logic that belongs together, otherwise the OR will run against all records, not just product_id = 1193